# XCode crash without error when distributing enterprise app

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having issues with XCode. My XCode crashes without error when trying to distribute enterprise app right after selecting "Automatically manage signing" and clicking next.

This is how to reproduce my issue:

1. Archive your app.
2. Open the Organizer window.
3. Click on Distribute App.
4. Select the Enterprise distribution method and click Next.
5. Select App Thinning All Compatible Device Variant, check Rebuild
   from Bitcode and Uncheck Include Manifest for Over-the-air and click
   Next.
6. Select Automatically manage signing and click next.
7. "Communicating with Apple" then Crash without error.

Comment: Same issue here were you able to get it solved?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason of this issue. Because the certificates and provisioning files 
are generated from not an Enterprise account. You can check again your App ID and make sure it have been upgraded to Enterprise before use it to generate files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, Xcode 11.3 was crashing while exporting enterprise build and while Communicating with Apple. I fixed this issue by configuring correct Enterprise team, certificate and profile in my app Signing and Capabilities Tab.

My crash was occurring because I was using my normal developer account in signing and capabilities which was not enterprise one and trying to distribute enterprise app.